# automatically open removable devices in explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, removable

is it possible to set the autoplay to always open removable devices in windows explorer? I used the settings offered in the autoplay dialog and set the openning in Explorer for almost all content types, but after inserting a flash disk, I get the dialog again.

I need this for my visually impaired sister - for her it is not comfortable always to select the appropriate item in menu or always close it and go to My Computer.

She uses Windows 7 Pro 64 bit.

thanks

Comment: Try `start - control panel - autoplay` and change it for each type of media. I don't know how to set it for all plug & play devices

Comment: Hmm, this is strange - I thought I set it for almost all the items - surely for "mixed-content" - however, as I checked it, it was set to ask for action - changed to open in Explorer and seeems to be solved now.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to `Start - Control Panel - Autoplay` and select the default action for each type of media. By default, Windows 7 has `autorun.ini` disabled for USB devices to protect against malware. If this doesn't solve your problem, you may need to enable `autorun.ini` and create it on the media for your sister.